# How to nest each statement to get objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
ab.c.click = function() {};
ab.c.focus = function() {};
ab.d.c = function() {};
ab.g.d = function() {};

data.c = $('.element');
data.g = $('.element');
```

I want to do an each statement that does the following:

do a for each on the ab

EXAMPLE: get the first part (c) and the second part (click)

using the (c) get the corresponding element from data (data.c)

```
$(document).on( (click), (elementfromdata), function() {});
```

I tried this but it did not work:

```
     $.each(ab, function(x){     
             $.each(x, function(g){
             var final = x + g;
         });
      });
```

please ask if more info needed.

Comment: I don't understand why the properties of `ab.d` and `ab.g` aren't valid event names. Shouldn't it be something like `ab.d.click` or `ab.g.hover`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```
for(coll in ab){ //coll corresponds to "c","d" etcetera
    if(ab.hasOwnProperty(coll)){

        for(handler in ab[coll]){ //handler corresponds to "click","focus" etcetera
            if(ab[coll].hasOwnProperty(handler)){

                $(document).on(handler, data[coll], ab[coll][handler]);

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @RobertHane One thing you might want to look into is storing the jQuery collections in the same object as their handlers. So for example, `ab.c.coll` would be `$('.whatever')`, and `ab.c.handlers` would be what it is now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the magical `this` variable.

```
$('.element').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: @RobertHane: I don't think I understand the question either, but this doesn't seem like a solution...

Comment: @elclanrs The OP has a bunch of jQuery collections stored in the `data` object, and handlers for those collections hierarchically stored in the `ab` object. For example, `ab.c` is an object that maps event name -> handler for the `data.c` collection. The OP is looking for a way to actually bind the handlers.

Comment: @elclanrs At least, that's what I think is going on.